# Is this splotchy purple pattern on short ribs ok?

Tags: beef

[image]

We’re making some short ribs, and noticed this weird pattern on the bone side of some of the ribs. What is this, and is it safe to eat?

As a side note, there is some silver skin on the other side of some of these ribs, but this pattern is distinct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its ink from a USDA meat inspection mark. The ink is non-toxic so it's safe to eat, just ugly.

Comment: Really? Seems like a very large and oddly shaped stamp!